# How can I stop re-sending approvals when an item is rejected in ServiceNow

Tags: loops, workflow, servicenow

I have a SN question about workflow activities. Ideally when a user in an approval group activity rejects the item, catalog tasks are re-opened and approvals re-sent. That works fine. However, in the event that another user rejects the item, we do not want to re-open catalog tasks and re-send approvals. i.e. looping over again. We just want to keep the comments from the second, third and so on approver. Any ideas on how to obtain this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

So just to understand what you're trying to accomplish:

1 user rejects, all other users approve: loop
2 or more users reject: cancel request

The easiest way to do this might be to use the workflow scratchpad and a script in the approval activity.

If you run a 'condition based on a script' in your workflow activity for the approvals, you could write to the workflow scratchpad with the actual number of rejections. Then you could use an if block to govern what happens when you leave the activity.

Alternately, you could add a condition to the approval workflow activity itself; a third option, based on the two existing ones (you can view the contents of any workflow activity condition by double-clicking on it). This would also require 'condition based on a script' to be active.